# ServiceBase.RequestAdditionalTime() in .Net 1.1

Tags: .net, windows, winapi, service

I need to delay the 30 second timeout when restarting a .Net 1.1 service.  Due to logistical reasons, I can  not upgrade to .Net 2.0 to take advantage of the ServiceBase.RequestAdditionalTime() method.

One work-around is to call SetServiceStatus at the beginning of the code.  However, for dependency purposes I need all of my code to execute before this is set.

I also looked into setting the registry key ServicesPipeTimeout, but would really prefer not to make a global change for all services since I don't know what impact that might have.

Is there any equivalent to calling the ServiceBase.RequestAdditionalTime() method in .Net 1.1?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at the source code of the [ServiceBase.RequestAdditionalTime](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.serviceprocess.servicebase.requestadditionaltime.aspx) method in .NET 2.0 (using a decompiler tool like [ILSpy](http://wiki.sharpdevelop.net/ILSpy.ashx)), you'll see that it's conceptually doing two things:

1. **Assigns** the specified amount of milliseconds to the `dwWaitHint` field of the [SERVICE_STATUS](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms685996%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) structure
2. **Invokes** the [SetServiceStatus](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686241%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) Win32 function passing the new [SERVICE_STATUS](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms685996%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) structure

You could implement the same functionality in .NET 1.1 using [P/Invoke](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa719104%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) to interact with the Win32 API.

Comment: Thanks Enrico.  That's what I ended up going with.  Just wanted to add this excellent intro to P/Invoke article by Jason Clark.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc164123.aspx

Comment: Running into a follow up issue regarding obtaining the status handle for the service.  See here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8389670/get-service-status-handle-after-initializing-service