# Get Service Status Handle after initializing service

Tags: winapi, service, interop, .net-1.1

I am calling the Win32 API from .Net 1.1 to request additional startup time for a service (.Net 2.0 and up is not an option currently).  Here is the pseudo-code I am calling within the OnStart() method.

```
private void OnStart(){
    private IntPtr statusHandle;
    private IntPtr serviceHandle;
    private IntPtr serviceControlManagerHandle;

    serviceControlManagerHandle = ServiceUtil.OpenSCManager(null, null, (uint)ServiceUtil.SCM_ACCESS.SC_MANAGER_ALL_ACCESS);
    serviceHandle = ServiceUtil.OpenService(serviceControlManagerHandle, this.ServiceName, (uint)ServiceUtil.SERVICE_ACCESS.SERVICE_ALL_ACCESS);

    //This fills the empty object with VALID data
    SERVICE_STATUS status = ServiceUtil.QueryServiceStatus(serviceHandle, ref status)

    //This returns a VALID pointer.
    statusHandle = ServiceUtil.RegisterServiceCtrlHandler(this.ServiceName, serviceHandle);
}
```

This part works just fine.  I receive valid (non IntPtr.Zero) handles for each and I can update the SERVICE_STATUS just fine.  However, I REALLY need this code to be in the Init() method (I am retrofitting a legacy service that is timing out).  But when I move this code to the Init() method, I can get a valid handle to the Service Control Manager and the Service itself, but NOT the Service Status.  My resulting, NON-WORKING, code appears as follows...

```
private void MyServiceClass(){
    InitializeComponent();

    private IntPtr statusHandle;
    private IntPtr serviceHandle;
    private IntPtr serviceControlManagerHandle;

    serviceControlManagerHandle = ServiceUtil.OpenSCManager(null, null, (uint)ServiceUtil.SCM_ACCESS.SC_MANAGER_ALL_ACCESS);
    serviceHandle = ServiceUtil.OpenService(serviceControlManagerHandle, this.ServiceName, (uint)ServiceUtil.SERVICE_ACCESS.SERVICE_ALL_ACCESS);
    statusHandle = ServiceUtil.RegisterServiceCtrlHandler(this.ServiceName, serviceHandle);

    //This fills the empty object with VALID data
    SERVICE_STATUS status = ServiceUtil.QueryServiceStatus(serviceHandle, ref status)

    //This returns an INVALID pointer.
    statusHandle = ServiceUtil.RegisterServiceCtrlHandler(this.ServiceName, serviceHandle);
}
```

In BOTH cases, QueryServiceStatus fills "status" with valid values.  However, only the first example sets "statusHandle" to a valid pointer.  How can I get a valid handle to the service's status struct before entering the OnStart() method?

Answer (score 0):

If the [RegisterServiceCtrlHandlerEx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms685058%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) function, which is most likely the one invoked by the `ServiceUtil.RegisterServiceCtrlHandler` method, fails **it will return an empty pointer**.

Try invoking the [GetLastError](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms679360%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) function to get back the details about what went wrong. My guess is that it's a timing issue. The **service itself may simply not be ready to accept handler functions** during initialization.

What exactly are you trying to achieve? We might be able to work out a different solution.

Comment: Enrico, I think you're right.  The GetLastError returns an unhandled exception 0xC0000005, access violation reading location 0xcdcdcdcd.  I am currently in the process of using [ILSpy](http://wiki.sharpdevelop.net/ILSpy.ashx) to reconstruct the service initialization process to see if I can build my own.  I will let you know my results.